# Issue with Preview of a Composable with Material Scaffold and TopAppBar

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

When I preview a Composable function with a Material Scaffold and TopAppBar I obtain the image below.

The `@Preview` function, I am using has the `showSystemUi = true`.

```
@Preview(showSystemUi = true)
```

In my opinion, even if I use the showSystemUi = true on Preview, the TopAppBar of the Scaffold should be placed correctly, and not be repeated. Can I assume this is a bug or is there any way to solve this problem?
Thanks,

[image: Emulator screenshot]

Comment: Remove systemUi and add appropriate width and height for your preview that should solve this problem. It's little inconvenient to see topbar from system UI.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a bug and I don't think that there is any way to solve this problem. The Android developer documentation clearly states that `@Preview(showSystemUi = true)` will show the status bar along with the action bar. You can check out their documentation here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling#preview-decoration

Comment: The document says that will show the status bar along with the action bar, but what would be expected is the action bar to be properly updated with what I define and there is no duplication.

Comment: If you want then you can file a bug or submit a feature request regarding this issue at this website: https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs